# NoClassFound com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver on Nexus 5->Android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to modify and implement GCM (hmkode) in eclipse.I have imported project in eclipse and performed the necessary steps for setup.

http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

After going through GCM sample on developer.google.com .The link says google includes GcmReceiver class by default.I removed old GcmBroadcastReceiver from hmkode sample and changed GcmMessageHandler to extend GcmListenerService instead of IntentService(in hmkode/original code).

Link:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Problem:
When I try to send message to the client the client crashes with following exception in logcat

**E/AndroidRuntime(20573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hmkcode.android.gcm-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(20573):

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2590)**

**My Class structure-**

```
     public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
     String mes;
     private Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super();
    }
//com.hmkcode.android.gcm.
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    public void showToast(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mes , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         });

    }



}
```

**Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnRegId;
    EditText etRegId;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid;
    String PROJECT_NUMBER = "164502923904";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetRegId);
        etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegId);

        btnRegId.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void getRegId(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    Log.i("GCM",  msg);


                } catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getRegId();
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hmkcode.android.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm.GcmMessageHandler" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also gcm.jar has been added as dependency and exported.

Comment: Where is your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Its eclipse project so no gradle used

Comment: Switch to Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse with regular android gcm jar, u need to add com.google.android.gcm.GcmReceiver instead of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver. This worked for me (at least temporarily)